Group Products are not sorted correctly according to their grouped price
I have a grouped product in magento 2 that is not sorted correctly in my category view. Due to the fact that a group product does not have its own price magento apparently takes the min_price (which is set to the price of the cheapest associated product) to sort it by price in ascending order.
